# Raphael.js text value animation

Tags: javascript, raphael

I'm trying to animate counter in raphael.js, but I've encountered with a strange behavior. In the middle of the animation text value is equal to `NaN` and I don't understand why.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="raphael.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
     <script type="text/javascript">
        var r = Raphael(0, 0, 400, 400);
        r.ca.strNumber = function (number) {
            var str = number + '';
            return {"text" : str};
        }

        $(document).ready( function() {
            var t = r.text(200, 200, "1").attr({"font-size": 50, "fill": "black"});
            t.animate({"strNumber": 999}, 500);
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

So what's wrong with it? How to fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to do an animation count from 1 to 999. I don't think .animate() can help you to do that, instead you can use the following code will count from 1 to 10:

```
<body>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var r = Raphael(0, 0, 400, 400);
    $(document).ready( function() {
        counter = 1;
        var t = r.text(200, 200, counter).attr({"font-size": 50, "fill": "black"});

       var myTimer = setInterval(function(){
          counter ++;
          t.attr('text', counter);
          if (counter>=10){
            clearInterval(myTimer);
          }
        }, 500);
    });
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

You got NaN because it does not have initial value for your custom attributes. Add this after creating your text:

t.attr({ strNumber: 0 }); // make initial value to 0, you can set this to any number that fits your need

Then you can do animation as normal